# D3 - Shrink Linear Scale Range

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a very simple stacked horizontal bar chart from a simple dataset containing 2 values.

1. I want to display the dataset values on the left and right of the bars respectively. The `<svg>` is 500px wide and I would like 
   the chart to be displayed from 100 to 400 so that I can accomodate `<text>` before and after the bars. For this I'm trying to shrink the range
   from [0, 500] to [100, 400] but result is not as expected.
2. I would also like to draw the chart without using layout.stack() so that I can use a simple dataset like [66852, 7550]

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yjodfkt/)

```
//Width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 60;

//Original data
//var dataset = [66852, 7550]
//changed to below to support layout.stack()
var dataset = [ [{y:66852}], [{y:7550}] ];

//Set up stack method
var stack = d3.layout.stack();

//Data, stacked
stack(dataset);

//Set up scales
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                return d.y0 + d.y;
            });
        })
    ])
    .range([100, 400]);

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal() 
    .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, h], 0.05);

//Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// Add a group for each row of data
var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
    });

// Add a rect for each data value
var rects = groups.selectAll( 'rect' )
    .data( function( d ) { return d; } )
    .enter()
    .append("rect") 
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {     
        return xScale(d.y0);        
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        console.log('y: '+yScale(i));
        return yScale(i);
    })  
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        console.log('width: '+xScale(d.y));
        return xScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr("height", 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, despite its name, your linear `xScale` is not linear (the image of 0 is 100). So when you use `return xScale(d.y);` for the width, you're adding 100 to the width of every rectangles (in mathematical terms, the function used is xScale(z) = 0.00211 * z + 100 : this is affine, not linear).

---

Edit, examples :

- a rect starting at d.y0=0 must have x=100
- a rect with d.y=0 must have width=0
- a rect with d.y0=71000 (around half the sum) must have x=250 (middle of the drawing)
- a rect with d.y=71000 must have width=150 (half the width of the drawing)

=> It is not possible to use directly the same scale for width and x position. So either you use different functions to compute width and x, or you cheat with an additional `transform` for x (see my original solution below).

---

The easiest solution is to have a `range` of `[0,300]` (instead of `[100,400]`), and put the drawing area within a `g` with `.attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")` to center the plot.

Second option (sounds like the one you'd prefer): use `xScale(d.y0+d.y) - xScale(d.y0)` for the width (instead of just `xScale(d.y)`). This directly computes the distance between left and right endpoints, i.e. it gives the width. It should work with any scale (not necessarily linear).

As for your second question, I don't really know another general way of doing this (other than writing your own drawing procedure, it won't be too hard). But you can easily translate a simple array into a layout-friendly one:

```
var dataset = [66852, 7550]
var layoutDataset = dataset.map(function(d){ return [{y:d}] });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've difficulty to understand why D3 won't take 100 as start value of the range while calculating the width. Ideally it should match or map 0 to 100 but no. In other words, how do I map domain such as [0, 500] to range like [100, 300] without having to use transform?

Comment: A lot! Thanks again! :)

Comment: I forgot to mention: in the first place, you can very well have negative values for your labels and adjust the `viewport` of the svg accordingly to let them show.

Comment: Hmm..I'll try that out. Thanks for the info.